# Split aggregated data table into multiple CSV files

Tags: r, csv

I have a data table with may rows containing data about usage of some specific services. This data describes the usage of different service types in different regions:

```
type     region     quantity     timestamp
small     A            2         05/01/15
small     B            1         05/01/15
big       A            1         05/01/15
small     A            2         06/01/15
small     B            1         06/01/15
big       A            3         06/01/15
...etc
```

I am performing some operations over the data series of every unique combination of type and region (each of these combinations produce its own time series so `small-A` should be treated independently from `small-B`, for example)

I already figured out how to do these kind of operations with aggregated data like this:

```
aggregatedDT <- DT[, .(quant = sum(quantity)), by = .(week, region,type)]
```

Now I need to save each data series into a separate CSV file. I am not sure if there are some built-in functionality to do such operation so I would like to know whether this is even possible.

My desired output would be:

**small-A.csv**:

```
week1: total quantity
week2: total quantity
...
```

And the same thing for **small-B.csv**, **big-A.csv** etc. Athe the moment, I have these data in one aggregated data.table but these csv files are meant as an input for another algorithm which needs to take the timeseries one by one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this to stay 'inside' data.table, while generating the appropriate filenames:

```
aggregatedDT[,write.csv(.SD,file=sprintf("%s-%s.csv", unique(type),unique(region))),
             by=.(region,type)]
```

Data used:

```
aggregatedDT <- data.table(expand.grid(week=1:2, region=c("A","B"),type=c("big","small")),
                           quant=1:8)
```

Comment: Wow, I hand no idea I can use the write function like that. Works like a charm! Thanks

Comment: `CJ` would be faster than `expand.grid`, and it directly returns a data.table.

Comment: True, but it was only used to generate the data, so unsure if it's really an issue here.

Comment: Great solution. Thanks. But the output files don't have the name of the 1st column. Could you include it? Also, you might want to use `fwrite{data.table}` to improve speed of the code.

Comment: I think you can change things for your situation, but this solution was obviously enough for OP.